# Styling an image container

Tags: html, css, styling

I have created my own CMS, but my image overview is still messed up.
Currently it is looking like this:
happens: http://i47.tinypic.com/raaybt.jpg

I'm trying to achieve this result (made this picture with photoshop)
http://i47.tinypic.com/30ualbm.jpg

How can i achieve the result i posted above?
Here is my HTML code:

```
                   <div id="main-content">
                   <div class="tab-content default-tab" id="tab1">
                        <div class="notification information png_bg">
                            <a href="#" class="close"><img src="resources/images/icons/cross_grey_small.png" title="Close this notification" alt="close" /></a>
                            <div>
                                Hieronder ziet u een overzicht van alle afbeeldingen die momenteel geupload zijn.
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div id="afbeeldingen">
                            <ul id="afbeeldingenlijst">
                                <li>
                                    <div class="afbeelding">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
                                        <a href="#">Verwijderen</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>

                                <li>
                                    <div class="afbeelding">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"/>
                                        <a href="#">Verwijderen</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                    </div></div>
```

and here is my css:

```
#main-content ul li {
    width:200px;
    float: left;
}
```

Thanks in advance (:

Comment: That'll be about 700 lines of code.

Comment: can it be you don't have `ul {list-style: none}`? use [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) to post an example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gqGXP/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside UL the elements are floated it causes 0px height of parent element, so you should have to clear that float for that add this css to your style sheet

```
    .clearfix {
      *zoom: 1;
    }

    .clearfix:before {
      display: table;
      content: "";
    }

    .clearfix:after {
      display: table;
      content: "";
      clear: both;
    }

and <ul class="clearfix">...</ul>
```

use this class for all parent element those having floated elements inside in that element(if needed)

and also add one more property to LI with existing properties to remove bullet points

```
li{
  ...
  ...
  list-style:none;
}
```

Or simply you could use

`overflow: hidden;` for parent element(i.e UL)

Comment: This worked! (:
Thanks a bunch, now i know what clearfix is used for..
Been wondering this lately.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to set display property to inline-block instead of float : left.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to clear the floating image elements that you have in your design.

The easiest way to do this is to add an overflow property to the parent e.g.

```
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Doing this should all the parent element to grow ij height and accommodate it's floating children without breaking the layout.